# CodeIgniter config file not finding database info?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having database connection issues.
Here is the error I get:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 338
```

Here is my database.php file settings:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dvp';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I've placed this code at the bottom of my database.php file:

```
echo '<pre>';
     print_r($db['default']);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo 'Trying to connect to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
  $dbh=mysql_connect
  (
    $db['default']['hostname'],
    $db['default']['username'],
    $db['default']['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);

    echo '<br />   Connected OK:'  ;
    die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . '--> Line: ' .__LINE__);
```

And the following info displays:

```
Array
(
    [hostname] => localhost
    [username] => user
    [password] => password
    [database] => dvp
    [dbdriver] => mysql
    [dbprefix] => 
    [pconnect] => 1
    [db_debug] => 1
    [cache_on] => 
    [cachedir] => 
    [char_set] => utf8
    [dbcollat] => utf8_general_ci
    [swap_pre] => 
    [autoinit] => 1
    [stricton] => 
)

Trying to connect to database: dvp
Connected OK
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is your user supposed to be empty?

Comment: Nope, that's the point. It doesn't seem to be loading any of the database vars from the config file.

Comment: Why did you add that to the bottom of your config file? Also, are you sure all your info is correct?

Comment: show us the file where you define those vars values

Comment: @WillemEllis as per these http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180277/#855024 instructions

Comment: That's a nice little bit of code to have. I'll have to save that!

Answer (score 0):

Ug, found the issue. Someone manually added a second set of db settings in another file and was calling them in from there. What a mess!